# what to do when "import folium" fails but "conda list" shows it

Tags: python, conda, folium

I have already installed folium, but import folium fails .

Also "conda list" for "base" env also lists folium

Giving example of pandas as well to show that pandas is getting imported which is also installed in the same location

```
folium                    0.12.1.post1       pyhd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge

(base) user1@user1-mac site-packages % conda list | grep -i pandas
pandas                    1.3.4            py38h743cdd8_0
```

If you see the site-packages directory...

```
(base) user1@user1-mac site-packages % pwd
/Users/user1/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages

(base) user1@user1-mac site-packages % ls -ld pandas*
drwxr-xr-x  21 user1  staff  672 Jan  3 12:23 pandas
drwxr-xr-x  10 user1  staff  320 Jan  3 12:23 pandas-1.3.4-py3.8.egg-info

(base) user1@user1-mac site-packages % ls -ld folium*
drwxr-xr-x  14 user1  staff  448 Jan  3 15:00 folium
drwxr-xr-x  10 user1  staff  320 Jan  3 15:00 folium-0.12.1.post1.dist-info
```

from  Jupyter notebook ->

```
$ import os
$ os.environ['PATH']
'/Users/user1/opt/anaconda3/bin:/Users/user1/opt/anaconda3/condabin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin:/Applications/apache-maven-3.6.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin'
```

I tried adding the path into $PATH variable

```
os.environ['PATH'] = os.environ['PATH'] + ':/Users/user1/Desktop/anaconda3/lib/python3.8'
```

But it did not solve the problem either . What else needs to be done ?

Answer (score 0):

If you fail to import a module with error `ModuleNotFoundError`, then this module must not be in your Python interpreter's searching path. You can check this path by:

```py
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', '/Users/xxx/.pyenv/versions/3.9.9/lib/python39.zip', '/Users/xxx/.pyenv/versions/3.9.9/lib/python3.9', '/Users/xxx/.pyenv/versions/3.9.9/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload', '/Users/xxx/.pyenv/versions/3.9.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages']
```

You can adjust this variable via Python code, or via the environment variable `PYTHONPATH`. The variable `PATH` is where your shell searches when entering a command. They are different things.

Comment: they are added , see here

`>>> print(sys.path) 
['/Users/user1/python-examples/webscraping/weathermap',
 '/Users/user1/Desktop/anaconda3/lib/python38.zip',
 '/Users/user1/Desktop/anaconda3/lib/python3.8',
 '/Users/user1/Desktop/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload',
 '',
 '/Users/user1/Desktop/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages',
 '/Users/user1/Desktop/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aeosa',
 '/Users/user1/Desktop/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/extensions',
 '/Users/user1/.ipython']`

Comment: @RajarshiGhosh No, the directory `/Users/user1/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages` is not in this list.